# Слово "хана"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Жаргонное слово "хана", то есть "конец", откуда оно вообще взялось в языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достоверной этимологии нет.
Вроде бы на санскрите есть созвучное слово со значением "убийство", но крайне маловероятно такое проникновение. 
В тюркских есть слово "хона" - комната, пространство, одно из значений которого якобы "могила". Если так, то это многое объясняет.

Comment: Уважаемый @behemothus, посмотрите мой комментарий на Ваши слова внизу (я ничего не знаю о происхождении жаргонного слова "хана", и пишу там немного о другом; но в ответ на Ваши слова)

Comment: @Maxim  А зачем вы пишете мне под чужим комментарием? Впрочем, ладно, в любом случае прочитаю. "Уважаемый" здесь излишне, роль обращения выполняет  "собака".

Answer (score 1):

Я встретил такое объяснение [на одном форуме](http://zhurnal.lib.ru/u/alloetokto/russkajafenjagoworjashajanaidish.shtml): хана (от ивр. חנה хана - делать остановку в пути, привал) - конец.

Comment: А кто вообще сказал, что слово из иврита?

Comment: >Я встретил такое объяснение на одном форуме

Comment: Я это понял. Только это не объяснение, максимум - версия. Объяснение включало бы как минимум изложение того, как иврит-слово проникло в русский. Вообще фонетические "объяснения" очень редко бывают не только правильными, но даже правдоподобными. Могу лишь подтвердить, что корень "тахана" в иврите есть (тахана - остановка), но как он используется, да еще в таком усеченном виде...

Comment: Интересно, что ***חנה*** - личное имя (Ханна, Анна) и прилагательное - цвет, коричнево-красный. А вот насчет остановки... Гугл такого не знает.

Comment: А, вот оно что.. ***חניה***. Одна буква пропущена - а как все меняет. Это да, что-то типа "стоянки". Но она и читается совсем по-другому. "Хэйна", наверное. надо уточнить.

Comment: Корень - это חֲנָה. Этот корень очень распространён в иврите (ханая - автостоянка, ханут – склад, магазин, махане - лагерь). См. [здесь](http://translate.academic.ru/%D7%97%D6%B2%D7%A0%D6%B8'%D7%94/ru/)

Comment: А впереди тогда что во всех этих якобы однокоренных словах? Я совсем не силен в иврите, но что-то мне не нравится такое вычленение "корня" из середины слова.

Comment: @Jacob Seleznev . Помимо חנה - хана , есть ещё и  הנח - ханах . Смотрите мой ответ .

Comment: @behemothus Уважаемый behemotus, я не знаю этимологию этого слова. тем не менее, ивритские слова попадали в русский язык через(к сожалению) одесский уголовный сленг, есть не меньше десятка примеров, это -- описанный феномен.

Слово haniya, חניה , "остановка", в иврите действительно есть, просто это -- старая (не современная ивритская) форма

при этом я не могу утверждать, что русское жаргонное Х. произошло отсюда.

(конечно, есть настоящие древнееврейские слова, законным образом пришедшие в русский язык с переводом Библии; простите за каламбур)

Comment: (превысил лимит) произношения hanaya тоже допустимо.

Comment: @behemothus (и соврененное ивритское chanaya, парковка для машин, есть реинтерпретация старого слова "остановка" (есть еще в Библии)

Comment: @Maxim Ну а я-то при чем здесь? Да, есть немало слов, которые через одесский жаргон и общую "феню" протикли в язык, с этим никто не спорит. Вопрос-то не в этосм, а в конкретном слове.

Answer (score 0):

Это слово армянского происхождения: оно происходит от двух слов: "хи" (почему) и "на" (он). Таким образом, очевидно, что слово "хана" означает "почему он!", что прекрасно коррелирует со смыслом этого слова. Например: "хана им" (почему он им). 
В свою очередь, выражение "хана им" восходит к семитскому (библейскому) этническому самоназванию племени Ханаанейцев (Ханааним). Отсюда следует близость армянского "хана" и семитского "ханааним".

Comment: Это что, шутка? До 1 апреля еще далеко.

Comment: @DocentI, ну, вот зачем вы тему "апнули"? :-) Я подумал, там какая-то интересная дискуссия началась, полез, как дурак, смотреть... Ну, пусть теперь другие тоже так думают!

Comment: Мейхана : "Ты кто такой? Давай, до свиданья!"

Comment: А я тут причем? Претензии к автору ответа

Comment: Автор ответа пока что никому здесь не известен. Я бы не стал читать заведомо неинтересную тему, обновленную неизвестно кем.

Comment: Задорнов в гостях у армянского радио.

Comment: Очередная ерунда от армян, колесо они тоже придумали...

Answer (score 0):

На иврите **חנה** **хана** действительно означает <<**делать остановку** / **привал**>> , как указывает **@Jacob Seleznev** . Но есть ещё другое : **הנח**  буквы : **ה** *хей*(**Х**) , **נ** *нун*(**Н**) , **ח** *хет*(**Х**-*гортанный*) /внимание: чтение справа-налево!/ может быть прочтено , как ХАНАХ . Среди значений : <<ОСТАВИТЬ ПОСЛЕ СМЕРТИ>> , + **זֵר**/*зэр*/ <<ВОЗЛОЖИТЬ ВЕНОК>> , +  **אֶת נִשקוֹ**/*эт нишко*/ <<СЛОЖИТЬ ОРУЖИЕ>> . Так что ивритная версия вполне состоятельна . Само слово <<ХАНА>> это же жаргон типа воровской *фени* . Скорее всего , именно из *фени* это словцо и привилось в значении <<КОНЕЦ/ГИБЕЛЬ>> . А воровская *феня* , как известно , вся наполнена евреизмами . См. ИРИС-словарь [ИРИС-словарь](http://www.slovar.co.il/translate.php) . Ниже , скриншот из ИРИС-словаря .  ===========================================================================  [image: הנח]

Comment: Следопыт, будьте осторожны, словарь Ирис -- исключительно низкого качества (лучше бы его не было...). Дрор несравнимо лучше, (и он -- под редакцией Эвен-Шошана), но даже в нем есть пара критических ошибок.   Белый оксфордский иврит-английский хороший, полный Эвен-Шошан отличный, есть в интернете

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, как и многие жаргонные и распространенные в просторечье выражения возникают от ситуационных моментов и реакции на них. И копаться в санскритах и ивритах просто не резонно. Социальные слои, где они зародились и более употребляемы, не дают на то повода. Все равно, что искать истоки в словах Эллочки-людоедочки: "жуть", "мрак"...
К примеру: кого-то обидели или "поддели", вобщем спровоцировали и обидчик в ответ скажем может среагировать, наряду с физическим выпадом (удар кулаком или орудием) выкрикнуть возглас: "Ха!На (тебе)!" И последствия таких выпадов с выкриком "Ха!На!" могли стать неким результативным определением этому выражению. 
Версия междометийного происхождения.

Answer (score -1):

"Инцидент при Номон-Хана" - так называли японцы сражение на "Халхин-Голе"(1939 г.), по названию высоты в этой местности. Возможно что советские солдаты тогда и ввели в оборот выражение "пришла хана".

http://dbpedia.org/page/Battles_of_Khalkhin_Gol